# How to make a "careless" socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I need to have a socket (or other method of IPC) with following behaviour:

1. writer needs to be able to send
   data to socket without blocking
2. if there is no one listening, the
       data are discarded
3. as usual, reader needs to be able
       to connect and recieve those data

What have i done:

created a socked by calling

```
sock = socket (PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); //sock is an integer
```

binded it with

```
struct sockaddr_un name;
memset(&name,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
name.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
strncpy (name.sun_path, filename, sizeof (name.sun_path)); //filename contains "/cosmos"
bind (sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
```

then made a poll on it

```
struct pollfd pld;
pld.events = POLLOUT;
pld.fd = sock;
pld.revents=0;

//in loop
poll(&pld,1,50);
if(pld.revents & POLLOUT)
   write(fr,mydata,19);
```

Tracing outputshows that write is executed (repeatedly).
To listen on it i have done:

```
struct sockaddr_un cos_name;
int cosmos;
char buffer[100];
memset(&cos_name,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
strncpy (cos_name.sun_path, COSMOS_SOCKET, sizeof (cos_name.sun_path));
memset(buffer,0,100);
cosmos = socket (PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
//check on cosmos being 0
if (connect(cosmos,(struct sockaddr*) &cos_name, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) != 0)
{
    printf("Connecting failed: %s.\n",strerror(errno));
    return;
}
printf("Listening successfully started.\n");
//loop
{
    read(cosmos,buffer,100);
    printf("Recieved: %s.\n",buffer);
}
```

However, "Recieved..." is never printed.

What needs to be changed to achieve desired functionality?
What should be the clause on the last loop? (i'm using a simple "run 1000 times now").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Er, I think you need to read up a bit on UDP sockets.

They're connectionless. You just send packets to a destination and hope someone is listening.

On the server side you use `recvfrom()` to read packets. In order to send a packet back to the client, you use `sendto()` with the `struct sockaddr *src_addr` that you passed into your `recvfrom()` (it's populated with the info for the client that sent the packet you just received).

The client needs to bind a port as well, and use `recvfrom()` to get packets back from the server.

Server side:

- bind port
- read packets with `recvfrom()`
- send packets with `sendto()` back to clients using info returned from `recvfrom()`

Client side:

- bind port
- send packets to server with `sendto()`
- read replies with `recvfrom()`

Comment: So. a) bind on recieveing end instead of connecting b) use sendto() and recvfrom() instead of read and write?
Trying now.

Comment: But you have just described a connection. Two-way communication is established, where server a) waits for a request from client to arrive b) sends data to him based on the info recieved.
That's not what i asked about at all.

Comment: There is *no* connection. Nothing is established. You are using UDP. This covers 1) and 2) in your question. 3) is up to you on how you would implement that. There's no "connection" to be made, so the client would really just be sending a request for something, and the server would reply. You have no idea if either end receives the messages, of course ... because you're using UDP. You'd need to build logic around that.

Comment: If that's not what you're looking for, then you can't use UDP. All of these answers are based around the fact that the code you wrote uses SOCK_DGRAM (UDP).

Comment: What function can be used to determine whether there are data for recvfrom or not?

Comment: The same as with TCP sockets. You use non-blocking sockets; if there's no data it returns -1. You can also you select() and poll()

Comment: Maybe i am doing it wrong, but using recvfrom() blocks program.
Thanks for your advice. I'll try and use poll now as well. Then, program will hopefully work as intended.

Comment: Because you're not using a non-blocking socket (at least in the code above, you're not). You would need to do `fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);` after the call to `socket()`.

Answer (score 0):

I love to toy with sockets in interactive Python shell, it's very illustrative. See how your problem is basically solved with UDP sockets:

```
#-- setup receiving on client
>>> from socket import *
>>>
>>> rsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> rsock.bind(("127.0.0.1", 7888))
>>> rsock.recv(100)
```

Client blocks waiting for data. Good, let's go send something to it!

```
#-- server
>>> from socket import *
>>> 
>>> sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> sock2.sendto("hello", ("127.0.0.1", 7888))
5
>>>
```

Ok, message sent. Switch to client console and see `'hello'`! `;)` Try it out, it's really fun.

---

By the way, PF_INET is not mandatory, SOCK_DGRAMs work in absolutely the same way with PF_UNIX.